# Reverse a sentence using stack in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

i want to reverse a sentence using stack in c.
eg. how are you => you are how.

i have written the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct rev
{
    char *var;
    struct rev *next;       
};
struct rev *top=NULL;
struct rev *temp,*test;
main()
{
    int start, j = 0;
    char *p="Hi, How are you? Hope everything is fine";
    char *s;
    char *t;
    *t = '\0';
    s = p;
    while(1) {
        if(*p == ' '|| *p == '\0') {
            printf("Inside if \n");
            *(t + j) = '\0';
            printf("This is t %s\n",t);

            if(top == NULL) {
                temp = (struct rev *)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->var=t;
                top = temp; 
            } else {
                temp = (struct rev *)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
                printf("This is going in stack %s\n", t);
                temp->var = t;
                temp->next = top;
                top = temp;
                printf("This is top %s\n", top->var);
            }
            j = 0;         
        } else {
            *(t+j) = *p;
            printf("%c\n", *p);
            j++;    
        }   
        if(*p == '\0') {
            break;
        }

        //printf("%c",*p);              
        p++;
    }
    struct rev *show;
    show = top;
    while(show != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", show->var);
        show = show->next;               
    }

    getch();      
}
```

It is storing correctly but on traverse it is giving only the final element.
i am not be able to figure it out what is the problem.
Here is my output window:-

[image]

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Its still giving the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `char *t` is just a pointer, make it point to malloced memory and then go ahead... I dont understand how the code is even running ... You are doing `*(t + j)` when t is actually pointing to junk.

On first look You are overwriting `t`... after parsing a string. i.e you set `j = 0` and overwrite previously stored string and your `struct rev` hold a pointer to this `t` hence 
you are getting `you? you? you?` as output. instead of having `char *var` in `struct rev` point to `t` .. your `char *var` point to a malloced memory and do `strcpy` or `strtok`

I just did a rough modification of your code and it worked for me on linux + gcc ... Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct rev
{
    char *var;
    struct rev *next;       
};
struct rev *top=NULL;
struct rev *temp,*test;
main()
{
    int start, j = 0;
    char *p="How are you?";
    char *s;
    char *t;
    t = malloc(1000);
    if (t == NULL) {
        //OUT OF MEMORY
        exit(1);
    }
    s = p;
    while(1) {
        if(*p == ' '|| *p == '\0') {
            printf("Inside if \n");
            *(t + j) = '\0';
            printf("This is t %s\n",t);

            if(top == NULL) {
                temp = (struct rev *)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->var = malloc(100);
                if (temp->var == NULL) {
                   //OUT OF MEMORY
                   exit(1);
                }
                strcpy(temp->var, t);
                top = temp; 
            } else {
                temp = (struct rev *)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
                printf("This is going in stack %s\n", t);
                temp->var = malloc(100);
                 if (temp->var == NULL) {
                   //OUT OF MEMORY
                   exit(1);
                }
                strcpy(temp->var, t);
                temp->next = top;
                top = temp;
                printf("This is top %s\n", top->var);
            }
            j = 0;
        } else {
            *(t+j) = *p;
            printf("%c\n", *p);
            j++;    
        }   
        if(*p == '\0') {
            break;
        }

        //printf("%c",*p);              
        p++;
    }
    struct rev *show;
    show = top;
    while(show != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", show->var);
        show = show->next;               
    }

    //getch();      
}
```

Here's the output:

```
H
o
w
Inside if 
This is t How
a
r
e
Inside if 
This is t are
This is going in stack are
This is top are
y
o
u
?
Inside if 
This is t you?
This is going in stack you?
This is top you?
you?
are
How
```

**PS:** I dont undertand in which part of the code you are implementing `push|pop` ... You are using list and telling you want a stack. Stack and List are 2 different data-structures.

Answer (score 2):

Read complete line. Tokenize string on whitespace, pushing each word to the stack. Pop the stack while printing.

Useful functions:

- [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)
- [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Complete solution can be done in less than 20 lines (including structure definitions, header files, etc.)

---

You also have a problem with *undefined behavior* in your code. You have a pointer `p` which points to a *constant* array of characters (all string literals are constant arrays of characters). Then you try to modify that constant array.

You might want something like this instead:

```
char arr[] = "Some string here";
char *p = arr;
```

---

And you have *another* case of undefined behavior as well: You have the pointer `t` which is not initialized. You then continue to dereference it. I would say that you are lucky to not get a crash.

You also don't update `t` in the loop, which you probably should.

Comment: I did the same thing.. I started reading the string. Upon encounter of  a whitespace i pushed the word into the word into the stack.. and continued the process.. Upon reaching the end of string. I stated to pop the elements of the stack and print them.. The problem is its just printing the last (top) element of stack..

Comment: @vicky Then you're not actually popping the stack properly.

Comment: This is what I am asking.. I am not able to figure out the error.. hope u could help me out.
Thanks

Comment: @vicky Updated my answer with a pretty serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by initializing variable `t` to point to a valid memory address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the logic of "show" is written incorrectly-

```
show = top;
while(show != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", show->var);
    show = show->next;               
}
```

pointing show to top and printing "show->next" is incorrect way of popping out from stack.

Comment: Can you offer the Original Poster also a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pop function-

```
int pop(STACK **head) {
if (empty(*head)) {                         
   fputs("Error: stack underflow\n", stderr);
   abort();
} else {                                    
    STACK *top = *head;
    int value = top->data;
    *head = top->next;
    free(top);
    return value;}}
```